Python 3.11 os can't read log files
I have a working logger module built on DBR 10.4/python 3.8 platform that creates the log and periodically export to a blob storage. Recently we've moved to DBR 15.2/python 3.11, and now the logger function is working but while reading the log file it's throwing the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have already created another post on it (log files are vanishing from the working directory when trying to read and export them in Python 3.11) but didn't get any solution, so here I'm trying to rephrase the issue and report the additional tests I've tried.
The logger function is as follows:
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import FileHandler

def define_logger(file_name, debug=False, clear_handlers=False, stream_level_debug=False, info=True):
    """
    :param file_name: Name of the .log file
    :param debug: If true, creates debug level .log file
    :param clear_handlers: to clear the previous log file handlers.
    :param stream_level_debug: receive the log debug level on console.
    :param info: If true, creates info level log file.

        Defines the logger and arranges the handlers based on the parameters.
    :return: logger instance

    Enables log functionality.
    """
    #file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
    #print(file_name)
    # define a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # the level should be the lowest level set in handlers
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # This is for removing all the handler from the logger instance
    # First time you are running this you don't need it, when you want to define new logger specify
    if clear_handlers is True:
        logger.handlers.clear()
        while len(logger.handlers) > 0:
            logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])

    # Format can be arranged
    # datefmt for formatting the time.
    log_format = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] - %(asctime)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s',
     datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

    # For logging into console
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    if not stream_level_debug:
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    else:
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    # For logging into Info.log
    if info:
        info_handler = RotatingFileHandler('{}_info.log'.format(file_name), backupCount=1)
        info_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
        info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.addHandler(info_handler)

    # If cfg['log_debug'] = True then it will also capture debug level logs and puts it into _debug.log file
    if debug:
        debug_handler = RotatingFileHandler('{}_debug.log'.format(file_name), backupCount=1)
        debug_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
        debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(debug_handler)

    return logger

The function where I'm calling it:
mainlog = str(datetime.now().strftime("log_%Y-%B-%d-at%H-%M"))
#mainlog = "log_2024-August-13-at10-04"
log = define_logger(mainlog, debug=cfg['log_debug'],
                    clear_handlers=True, stream_level_debug=cfg["stream_level_debug"])

log.info('=' * 80)
log.info('>>>  log')
log.info('-' * 80)

# Defining blob_outpath
blob_outpath = cfg['blob_outpath']
log.debug('blob_outpath {}'.format(blob_outpath))

# Upload the log to blob drive
print('1st time ', os.listdir()[-2:])
print(os.path.abspath('{}_info.log'.format(mainlog)))
log2blob(env, mainlog, blob_outpath, cfg['log_debug']) #works fine at this point, if I 
           put delay=True while defining the handler, it gives the error at this point
#some commands
log.debug(f"{'-'*10} some configs")
log.debug(f"{'-'*10} some comments")

print('2nd time ', os.listdir()[-2:])
log2blob(env, mainlog, blob_outpath, cfg['log_debug']) #fails here although I can see the log files listed in the output of above print statement 

The function where the error is happenning:
def log2blob(env, log_name, blob_outpath, log_debug):
    """
    :param env: environment (UAT)
    :param log_name:
    :param blob_outpath: path to log files will be uploaded
    :param log_debug:

        ** If working on UAT uploads the logs to blob.
        ** If the environment is local then it is not needed.

    :return: None
    """
    if env == 'UAT':
        upload_blob_driver('{}_info.log'.format(log_name),
                                "{}{}".format(blob_outpath, '/logs'),
                                '{}_info.log'.format(log_name))
        if log_debug:
            upload_blob_driver('{}_debug.log'.format(log_name),
                                    "{}{}".format(blob_outpath, '/logs'),
                                    '{}_debug.log'.format(log_name))

def upload_blob_driver(driver_file, blob_path, file_name):
    blob = conn.get_blob_instance(blob_path, file_name)
    if blob.exists():
        blob.delete_blob()
    #logpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'log')
    #full_path = os.path.join(logpath, driver_file)    
       
    full_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), driver_file)
    #full_path = Path(logpath, driver_file)
    print(full_path)
    with open(full_path, "r+b") as data: # here we receive the FileNotFoundError: 
                                           [Errno 2] No such file or directory
        blob.upload_blob(data)

To check the file's existence, if I run os.listdir("logpath"), I don't see the logfiles listed, but if I run %sh ls -al logpath I can see the logfiles there. If I run os.listdir("logpath") again, I can see the logfiles now. In the documentations it's mentioned that since python 3.9 there's this addition of emit(record) module (link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.emit), and also the warnings which I think (but not sure) is related to my issue, but couldn't find any workaround for the same.
According to one suggestion in my previous post I've also tried to compare the output of
import os as os
id
(print(os.popen("id").read()))
(print(os.popen("logpath/logfile").read()))

for Python 3.8 & 3.11. In both versions for the first command I have
> uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

But for the second command I receive a blank output in Python 3.8 and the following message in Python 3.11
> logpath/logfile:> 1: [INFO]: not found
> logpath/logfile:> 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I checked the env and in both cases they return
> 'SHELL': '/bin/bash'

I'm unsure if it's related to my log file not found problem, but mentioned if it'd be helpful for diagnosing the issue.
Any help would be really helpful as I've scoured the internet/forums on this issue for over a month and didn't find any relevant solution so far.

what does '    print(full_path)' print ?

What is the function log2blob(env, mainlog, blob_outpath, cfg['log_debug']) does. please add the code of this function.

Also what is the blob output path?

@ticktalk print(full_path) prints the log file with it's path. So basically logpath/logfile. Which means prior to open the file, the logfile is still being recognized by python

@JayashankarGS the log2blob provides the blob credentials so that the log file can be exported. blob outpath is the location where the log file is to be exported. I've added the code in the question.

This is possibly due to file system cache. When do os.listdir() it gives you cached view of the directory. And when you do shell command it directly query on file system.
So, possible solution is list the directory using subprocess or os.system like below.
os.system("ls -al logpath")

OR
import subprocess
command = f"ls logs"
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()

So, you create a function to run this subprocess.
def runsubprocess(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return output.decode().split('\n')[-3:-1]
    

Next, call this function after doing logs every time.
Code:
mainlog = str(datetime.now().strftime("logs/log_%Y-%B-%d-at%H-%M"))
log = define_logger(mainlog, debug=True,clear_handlers=True)
print(mainlog)

log.info('=' * 80)
log.info('>>>  log')
log.info('-' * 80)
log.info('>>>  running subprocess')
runsubprocess("ls log")


blob_outpath = "data"
log.debug('blob_outpath {}'.format(blob_outpath))

print('1st time ', os.listdir('logs')[-2:])
print(os.path.abspath('{}_info.log'.format(mainlog)))
log2blob("UAT", mainlog, blob_outpath, True)

log.debug(f"{'-'*10} some configs")
log.debug(f"{'-'*10} some comments")
log.info('>>>  running subprocess')
runsubprocess("ls logs")

print('2st time ', os.listdir('logs')[-2:])
log2blob("UAT", mainlog, blob_outpath, True)

Here, i am logging all the files inside a folder logs and after every logging i am calling runsubprocess function.
Output:
[INFO] - 2024-08-30 10:30 - command-3200112807499306-4214193611 - <module> - ================================================================================
[INFO] - 2024-08-30 10:30 - command-3200112807499306-4214193611 - <module> - >>>  log
[INFO] - 2024-08-30 10:30 - command-3200112807499306-4214193611 - <module> - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] - 2024-08-30 10:30 - command-3200112807499306-4214193611 - <module> - >>>  running subprocess
logs/log_2024-August-30-at10-30
1st time  ['log_2024-August-30-at10-30_info.log', 'log_2024-August-30-at10-30_debug.log']
/Workspace/Users/xyz.com/logs/log_2024-August-30-at10-30_info.log
/Workspace/Users/xyz.com/logs/log_2024-August-30-at10-30_info.log
[INFO] - 2024-08-30 10:30 - command-3200112807499306-4214193611 - <module> - >>>  running subprocess
/Workspace/Users/xyz.com/logs/log_2024-August-30-at10-30_debug.log
2st time  ['log_2024-August-30-at10-30_info.log', 'log_2024-August-30-at10-30_debug.log']
/Workspace/Users/xyz.com/logs/log_2024-August-30-at10-30_info.log
/Workspace/Users/xyz.com/logs/log_2024-August-30-at10-30_debug.log

and in blob storage.


Before reading your answer, I have just implemented something similar, I'll post it as a seperate reply.

So based on my initial tests I've added the following line in my function where I'm calling the logger.
mainlog = str(datetime.now().strftime("log_%Y-%B-%d-at%H-%M"))        
log = define_logger(mainlog, debug=cfg['log_debug'],
                        clear_handlers=True, 
stream_level_debug=cfg["stream_level_debug"])    
logpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'log')
commandstring = f" ls -al {logpath}"
subprocess.call(commandstring, shell=True)

I need to run the subprocess only once after creating the log like shown above and it works. I'm going to implement @JayashankarGS's solution to hide the ls output. But, to be honest, I'm not sure if this certifies as an answer or a workaround. If anyone can shed some more light on the topic (e.g. is the cause related to python 3.11 or DRV 15.2/ is there any other way to tackle this) that'll be really helpful.
